# List of lists to row in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of lists:

```
list = ['John', ['Jack', 'Michael', 'Ian'], ['Melissa', 'Hannah']]
```

Which I want to transform into a row of an existing Dataframe:

```
Name         Children              Siblings
John     Jack, Michael, Ian     Melissa, Hannah
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this?

I'm new to Pandas and I have only found ways of converting lists into columns into a new dataframe for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(letters).T
df.columns = [0, 1, 2]

print (df)
   0  1  2
0  a  b  c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap it in brackets:

```
arr = ['John', ['Jack', 'Michael', 'Ian'], ['Melissa', 'Hannah']]
df = pd.DataFrame([arr], columns=['Name', 'Children', 'Siblings'])

   Name              Children           Siblings
0  John  [Jack, Michael, Ian]  [Melissa, Hannah]
```

Since you mentioned you are appending to an existing dataframe:

```
df

   Name              Children           Sublings
0  John  [Jack, Michael, Ian]  [Melissa, Hannah]

df.append(pd.DataFrame([arr], columns=df.columns)).reset_index(drop=True)

   Name              Children           Siblings
0  John  [Jack, Michael, Ian]  [Melissa, Hannah]
1  John  [Jack, Michael, Ian]  [Melissa, Hannah]
```

Comment: The problem with this is that im trying to **add** to an existing dataframe. I have tried creating the dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'CHildren', 'Siblings'])` and then adding to it: `df.append(list).T` but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: @machetazo I lost my mind for a second, just updated my answer with something 100x cleaner